# knockout.js - lazy loading of templates

Tags: knockout.js

So I come from a templating workflow that involves creating a data object (akin to a view model in knockout) passing that to a templating engine (jstemplate in our case), rendering the template using that data object, and appending it to the dom.

How do I achieve a similar work flow with knockout?  Is the "if" control flow what I'm looking for?  Or sticking my templates in script tags without data-bind attributes and adding them dynamically later and processing the template like ko.applyBindings(viewModel, node)?

I'm curious how others lazy load templates using knockout.

Also, extra credit if you can tell me why the js fiddle below doesn't work as I would expect it to.  I'm trying to learn the if control flow binding and this doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/JJgJ7/1/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several directions that you can go for something like this:

you can apply different view models to different elements, as you mentioned like:

```
var viewModelOne = { ...  };
var viewModelTwo = { ...  };
ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, containerElementOne);
ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, containerElementOne);
```

You can even dynamically apply a binding with its data to an element like:

```
var viewModelOne = { ... };
ko.applyBindingsToNode(containerElement, { template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: items }, viewModelOne);
```

Would be like this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gYk6f/

You can also do something like:

```
var mainViewModel = {
   sideBarModel = ko.observable(),
   contentModel = ko.observable()
};
```

Then, bind it like:

```
<div data-bind="with: contentModel"></div>
<div data-bind="with: sideBarModel"></div>
```

They, can even be nested like:

```
<div data-bind="with: contentModel">
   ...
   <div data-bind="with: $root.sideBarModel"></div>
</div>
```

Since, the models are observable, they can initially be empty and get populated on demand.

You can certainly use named templates in those cases as well like:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: "contentTmpl", data: contentModel }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: "sideBarTmpl", data: sideBarModel }"></div>
```

For the Extra Credit question:

`p` tags cannot contain other block level elements (like your `div`).  The browser moves it out of the `p` tag.  Replace your `div` with a `span` and it will behave like you are expecting (or replace `p` with `div`).

Comment: Great stuff!  By the way, thanks for taking the time to comment on my questions as of late!  I'm really digging knockout, and it's making my life much easier (coming from the backbone camp).  As far as this is concerned, I think I'm going to explicitly apply bindings to specific nodes, so the "templates" section of the dom won't be bound / rendered until I need it.  Thanks RP!

Answer (score 13):

I know the answer is still old by I guess you'd be interested to look at this. This is my pattern. One might say that I'm abusing the concept of knockoutjs but here it is... it works!

First you need to add an empty template, this is needed for knockout to load at least a template. If you provide something invalid, knockoutjs will sadly fail to work and abort what it was doing...

Let say you have this.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-emtpy">

</script>
```

Cool now lets take a look at how templating works in knockout, the knockout template is just a binding actually so it is checked at runtime and all the fancy thing you can do before works. And that mean that you can have things like that.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: activeTemplate, data: contentModel }"></div>
```

where activeTemplate could be an observable object! Oh so observables do works there... when the observable object changes, then the template is notified and will infact rerender with the correct template.

Now that you understand that we can actually set a template and change it in the future, you understand that until our template is loaded we will send knockout the empty template. There won't be any binding error because there is nothing to bind in nothing!

Now lets take a look at this!

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate('reports'), data: contentModel }"></div>
```

Where getTemplates is defined as:

```
window.getTemplate = function (name) {
    var baseUrl = "/templates/";

    var loaded = ko.observable(false);

    var template = document.getElementById('template-' + name);

    if (template) {
        loaded(true);
    } else {
        jQuery.get(baseUrl + name + '.html', function (data) {
            var scriptTag = $('<script type="text/html" id="template-' + name + '"></script>');
            scriptTag.html(data);
            $('head').append(scriptTag);
            loaded(true);
        });
    }

    return ko.computed(function () {
        if (loaded()) {
            return 'template-' + name;
        } else {
            return "template-empty";
        }
    })();
};
```

To sum it up, we are creating an observable loaded defaulted to `false`. If we find the template, we change the value to true. If not, we will try to load it with jQuery (load it with however you like... you could definitely put a text area and load the template from there. Anything is possible...).

We return a computed value that depends on the `loaded` observable. When loaded becomes true, it will return the id of the loaded template. For some reasons, knockoutjs requires the text to be inside the script html tag. That's why I update the script tag with html.

So that's it. Also, I might be wrong and I'm not sure how does knockout handle templates but it could be possible to switch loaded on and off to reload templates... And that means that you can have dynamically loaded and editable template awesomness!!!!

Also notice that I do execute the computed value just before returning it. And notice that the function is a global... To fix that! Create your own binding to make something like that:

```
<div data-bind="lazy_template: { name: "reports", data: contentModel }"></div>
```

And then you're good to go. All you have to do is to put the loading logic inside a custom binding.

I'll create a project on github with everything working I wish it will help. I'll update later with the url.

Might not be stable because I hacked it in half an hour but it works for me. I'll probably have to write some tests one day but anyway. Have fun!
https://github.com/llacroix/knockout-lazy-template

Comment: @loic-faure-lacriox, New to KO here, but after the `<div data-bind>` declaration with the call to `getTemplate` do you call `ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel())` like normal? It's always returning `Cannot find template with ID template-empty`. By the function above, that should only return if `loaded()` is false, but it's loading and injecting my template into the markup just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not right, if you look above, it will return a `computed` object that either return the right id for the template or `template-empty`. Since it is a computed object, the value can change. When the loading callback is fired, it will return the right id for the template. This is more a trick to show an empty template while the template is loading then switching back to the template we wanted. For it to work, you'll have, as I wrote above, to add an element with the id "template-empty" with a blank space or anything. This template will be shown while the other one is getting loaded.

Comment: If you're using the library I linked, it is not automatically appending an empty template to head. I'll update it soon and add some new things.

Comment: Nice! Exactly was I was looking for. I'll be using this in some upcoming projects.

Comment: Nice thing just the thing i was looking for in my case!