# Single page application using mvc3 knockout.js and sammy.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, sammy.js

I'm stuck on one particular part of my project which consists of the components mentioned in the title.

I currently have a proof of concept that works the way I want it to work:

- Sammy is integrated into the knockout viewmodels (as per the tutorial
  on the knockout site)
- the views are loaded on demand by a controller
  (so I don't have to define every single view on the application page)

In my current situation I instance the viewmodels when the application starts (if I don't instance them, Sammy will not handle the routing). The problem is where the view is loaded and swapped by Sammy. I have to make a call to ko.applyBindings for KO to bind to the view. But its bad practice to repeatedly call applybingings.

My question, how do I bind to my views that are loaded on demand? I can't call ko.applybindings since that would create a memoryleak when the view is loaded more than once.

Here is an example VM with the offending ko.applyBindings:

```
function serviceInfoVm() {
var self = this;

self.ObjectKey = ko.observable();
self.Service = ko.observable();

self.LoadService = function () {
    $.get('ServiceData/Detail', { serviceId: self.ObjectKey() }, function (data) {
        self.Service(data);
    });
};

$.sammy('#content', function () {
    this.get('#/service/:id', function (context) {
        var ctx = context;
        self.ObjectKey(this.params['id']);

        self.LoadService();

        $.get('Content/ServiceInfo', function (view) {
            ctx.app.swap(view);
            ko.applyBindings(self);
        });
    });

}).run();
};
```

Anyone with some pointers and/or solutions to this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use sammy swap instead of knockout templating? Have a look at external templates in html files plugin https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine that should do what you require (if I've understood correctly)

Comment: I wanted to load the views dynamically.. but abandoned the idea now. See my own answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution but another approach:

Ended up abandoning the idea of loading the views dynamically.
Now my views are always present in the page and the visibility is triggered by this code:

```
var app = function () {
var self = this;

self.State = ko.observable('home');

self.Home = ko.observable(new homepageVm());
self.User = ko.observable(new userInfoVm());

$.sammy(function () {

    this.get('#/', function (context) {
        self.State('home');
    });

    this.get('#/info/:username', function (context) {
        self.State('user');
        self.User().UserName(context.params['username']);
        self.User().LoadInfo();
    });

}).run();
```

};

And the div visibility is triggered this way:

```
<div id="homeView" data-bind="with: Home, visible: State() === 'home'">
```

This way the ko.applyBindings only needs to be called once when the app starts.
The viewmodel above is bound to our shell page.

More on this [here](http://www.itq.nl/blogs/post/ASPNET-MVC3-Knockout-JS-and-Sammy-JS-e28093-Revisited.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You have the Sammy code in the viewmodel, which can work great if that viewmodel will be present and you want sub viewmodels and views to be loaded. So I assume that is what you are trying to do. Food for thought ... separate the sammy code into its own module (I call mine router in router.js) and let it manage the navigation separate from any viewmodel.

But back to your code ... you could set up your subviews and subviewmodels and use applybindings on them prior to the sammy.get being called. Basically, you are registering your routes in advance. Then the sammy.get just navigates to the new view, which is already data bound.

Answer (score 0):

Calling applyBindings on the specific element in the returned template is an option:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, htmlNode)
```

Also see this question with regard to lazy loading templates: [knockout.js - lazy loading of templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422984/knockout-js-lazy-loading-of-templates)

And docs here for applyBindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html