# Knockout: Swapping in HTML That Uses Child ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js

I have an application that builds a small page upon load, which presents the user with navigation options. When the user selects a navigation option, the page creates an object representing the ViewModel of the selected navigation option, then gets the corresponding HTML from the server and places it inside of a div.

My expectation is that I could get the HTML, use a Knockout HTML binding to put it into the div (wrapped in a container div with a preselected ID), then bind the container div to the ViewModel.

However, I get errors when I try to do this. This seems very much in line with what Knockout is supposed to do, so I'm a little puzzled about what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have created a fiddle to encapsulate the problem (clicking the links does nothing):

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgh44

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: modules">
                <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.goTo.bind($data), text: $data"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="body" data-bind="html: curBody">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function GlobalVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.curVM = ko.observable();
    self.test = ko.observable('test');

    self.curBody = ko.observable('body');    
    self.modules = ko.observableArray();

    self.goTo = function(module) {
        if (module == 'Test1') {
            self.curVM(new SubVM1());

            self.curBody('<div id=\'realbody\' data-bind=\'text: curVM().test1\'></div>');
            ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById('realbody'));
        }

        if (module == 'Test2') {
            self.curVM(new SubVM2());

            self.curBody('<div id=\'realbody\' data-bind=\'text: curVM().test2\'></div>');
            ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById('realbody'));
        }
    };

    self.initialize = function() {
        self.modules.push('Test1');
        self.modules.push('Test2');
    };
}

function SubVM1() {
    var self = this;

    var test1 = ko.observable('test1');
}

function SubVM2() {
    var self = this;

    var test2 = ko.observable('test2');
}

var vm = new GlobalVM();
vm.initialize();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Look into the `template` binding and using an `observable` to store the template name. That will let Knockout handle the bindings automatically.

Comment: I have messed with templates, but I didn't like needing to embed them all in my layout view. Is it possible to dynamically retrieve the template when I need it, so the initial page doesn't come with a bunch of template code, most of which is not immediately needed, which would presumably make the page load slower?

Comment: (Oh, and thank you--I had kinda forgotten about templates, but it's possible I gave up on them too soon.)

Comment: You might want to look at the <a href="https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine">External Template Engine</a> plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using templates would probably be the best way to go for this. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgh44/7/) demonstrating this.

I added an observable that tracks the current "page"

`self.currentPage = ko.observable('Home');`

then in your `goTo` method, I changed it to be this

```
self.goTo = function(module) {
    self.currentPage(module);
};
```

and added the templates to the html.

#### Edit

I just saw your comments on your original post. Yes, you can load templates dynamically. You can load a template by dynamically adding that template to the DOM. Example:

```
$.get(templateurl, function(data){
    $('body').append('<div style="display:none">' + data + '<\/div>');
});
```

If you have a number of templates (or any, really), it's cleaner and easier to work with if you keep the templates in separate files - separated from the HTML of your primary view. You could then load them all into your view via ajax. However, loading in templates AFTER you have called `ko.applyBindings` won't work if you apply the bindings to the entire page. Some options are calling `ko.applyBindings` on individual DOM elements or using `ko.renderTemplate` - see [this SO post on lazy loading KO templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422984/knockout-js-lazy-loading-of-templates) for some great ideas.

Comment: Well, what I am doing now is pulling out some HTML (essentially a template, but not marked as such), and the HTML contains data-bound fields which reference fields in the parent ViewModel's "currentViewModel" observable, which changes dynamically when the page does, and will have different fields each time. I put the HTML that comes back from the server (the current template) into a DIV, just updating the innerHTML after getting it by ID. I then try to call ko.applyBindings on just the DIV, but I get the "cannot apply bindings to the same element twice" error from this. I'll try your link.