# Knockout partial view dynamic lazy loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am currently stuck with a scenario that I need to achieve and I am hoping you would be able to help me.

The scenario I am facing is as follow:

I am displaying a list of objects with a basic summary of information. These objects are populated from c# code via a web service call that retrieves the data. For each one of these objects that are then displayed there is a select button. When this select button is clicked, another div right below the current summary div should load a partial view. This partial view must also retrieve more data via web service and display the detailed view for the current object that was selected.

I have read the article on using the ko.onDemandObservable (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html) which seems to be doing what I want, but I am unsure on how to re use the same template as detail view for each summary object.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Good tutorial here http://tech.pro/tutorial/1745/lazy-loading-a-viewmodel-with-knockoutjs and similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422984/knockout-js-lazy-loading-of-templates

Comment: I think the tutorial you provided from tech.pro will cater for what I need, but how do I populate the people from initial load? I have tried using an ajax call in the following way:   $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetPeople","Home")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url
        }).success(function (data) {
            var dd = data.peepS;
            alert(dd);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(function (dd) {

                vm.people.push(new Person({ id: dd.Id, firstName: dd.FirstName }));
            });
        });
    });